# Camera returning black images in android 10

Tags: android, performance, camera, android-10.0

I have made a custom camera module for my application but after updating my device os to android 10 its giving black images , I have  used  android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" this in application tag to resolve storage issue in android 10 , If someone also faced same  issue and resolved it please give some suggestion , Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please share some code for better clarification.

Comment: its working fine for below android 10 , I just wants to know if there are some updates due to which we have to update something like requestLegacyExternalStorage .